# REGEX rewrite issue to allow hyphen

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have a web service that I have a rewrite on. I need to be able to allow hyphens or dash in the query. 
Here is my rewrite:

```
rewrite ^/app/api/sanction/([0-9]+)/athleteList/([a-zA-Z0-9,]+)/-([0-9,]+)$ /app/athleteList.phtml?s=$1&l=$2&c=$3 last;
```

The query works fine like this:

```
/app/api/sanction/35172/athleteList/MLEVEL07/25001,24450
```

However when I put a dash or hyphen here, the query will fail.

```
/app/api/sanction/35172/athleteList/MLEVEL-07/25001,24450
```

As you can see, I have the hyphen listed in the regex, unsure of what I may be doing wrong here...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should place the hyphen in the previous group :

```
([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)/([0-9,]+)
```

This will, however, match "---1020-,-02-1-," and i'm not sure this is what you want. Hence my first proposition, corrected now:

```
([a-zA-Z0-9,]+)(-([0-9]+))?/-([0-9,]+)
```

This will match only "weofhw234fhweo,sdfsff3284982-20423400" and not "--,j2j,f9223-2-3402--0d-f0s-f"

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misplaced the dash. It should be like this

```
rewrite ^/app/api/sanction/([0-9]+)/athleteList/([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)/([0-9,]+)$ /app/athleteList.phtml?s=$1&l=$2&c=$3 last;
```

Note that "-" was moved from after "/" into inside brackets. If dash is the last character inside square brackets, it doesn't have a special meaning to mark a range of characters (like in a-z).

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `-` inside `([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)`, at the end of the `[]` character class, and remove the hyphen after the next `/`:

```
rewrite ^/app/api/sanction/([0-9]+)/athleteList/([a-zA-Z0-9,-]+)/([0-9,]+)$ /app/athleteList.phtml?s=$1&l=$2&c=$3 last;
#----------------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^
```