# Regular expression numbers and hyphens

Tags: php, regex

I have a function that searches a string for a letter and/or number combination which works well, except sometimes that combination also contains a hyphen which I would like to match too. The regex below is taken from within a larger regex pattern match, but this is the part of the expression that i am stuck on.

For example:

([A-Za-z0-9-]+)

Matches the string 123 or 123A but it does not match 123-125 or 123A-125A

I'm sure it is a simple solution but it's not my forte.

thanks in advance

```
$key= preg_replace("/http:\/\/www.website.com\/[0-9]+\/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)_([A-Za-z_]+)_(MUSIC|VIDEO|PHOTOS)_([A-Z_]+)_(..+)_([0-9]+)/i", '${1}, ${2}, ${3}, ${4}, ${5}, ${6}', $url);
```

Comment: Seems like it matches to me.  Can you post the code that shows how you are using it?

Comment: i'm pretty sure you're supposed to use delimiters that are NOT in your pattern, escaped or not.

Comment: what if i did ([A-Za-z0-9][-A-Za-z0-9]?+)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8882073/regex-rewrite-issue-to-allow-hyphen

Comment: thanks @MarshallHouse i think the hyphen may have been a special character

Comment: This part of your pattern: `([a-z_]+)_` ... I don't think the underscore should be in your character set.

Answer (score 0):

simple, you need to escape the hyphen in your character set:

```
([A-Za-z0-9\-]+)
```